# How to sort many to many through a join model data with Ember.js and Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models with a many to many relationship through a join model because I need to store some relationship attributes in the association table.

The models are:

```
App.Module = DS.Model.extend({
   name: DS.attr('string'),
   ...
   modulesCourses: DS.hasMany('moduleCourse', { async: true })
});

App.Course = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    ...
    modulesCourses: DS.hasMany('moduleCourse', { async: true })
});

App.ModuleCourse = DS.Model.extend({
    character: DS.attr('string'),
    enabled: DS.attr('boolean'),
    module: DS.belongsTo('module', { async: true }),
    course: DS.belongsTo('course', { async: true })
});
```

When I get a module I can see its courses and the relation properties through the `modulesCourses` like this:

```
{{#each moduleCourse in module.modulesCourses}}
    Course: {{moduleCourse.course.name}} Character: {{moduleCourse.character}}
{{/each}}
```

But I need to sort the courses by name before displaying them. As the relations are defined as `async: true` the courses are fetched asynchronously so I think I should wait to have them all before trying to sort them.

Here I'm totally lost. I have tried some solutions but I can't get them sorted. Here there is an example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vugeqi/4/edit

Have you got any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would have expected your `sortBy` call to work as well, I've replaced it instead with a more succinct computed property, which seems to do the trick:

```
App.ModuleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  uname: function() {
    return this.get('name').toUpperCase();
  }.property('name'),

  moduleCoursesSorting: ['course.name'],

  sortedModulesCourses: Em.computed.sort('modulesCourses', 'moduleCoursesSorting')

});
```

You can view the functioning JSBin [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/muqaxohapa/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Perfect! It's nice and clean. The fact that the `sortBy` didn't work drove me crazy and I was trying more complex solutions that were wrong. Thanks!